# Proper Cleanup when using chained WndProcs

Tags: c++, c, winapi, wndproc

When building a chain of WndProcs using `SetWindowLongPtr`, we store the parent WndProc (the one that has less importance in the chain), so we are able to restore it and call it, like so:

```cpp
LONG_PTR oldProc = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, &myWndProc);

WndProc myWndProc(HANDLE hWnd, ...) {
  return CallWndProc(oldProc);
}
```

This is just a rough pseudocode from the top of my head, so please don't focus on that.

The problem with this, however, is, that when trying to remove `myWndProc` from the chain, like so:

```cpp
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, oldProc);
```

We effectively set the proc, that was in place when first hooking, as the topmost WndProc.
This means, that all WndProcs, that have been added *after* `myWndProc` (e.g. all kinds of Overlays), suddenly won't be called anymore.
Furthermore all hooks that are added afterwards point to invalid memory with their `oldProc`.

This means, hooks done that way can't be properly unloaded without messing something up.
While this would be fixable if all WndProcs belong to the same (our) codebase, this is not fixable with external code.

I haven't found a `WM` that would be called when a new WndProc is set, so it's also not possible to keep track of which WndProcs have been registered after the current handler, so one could re-build the chain. That would still not solve the issue with invalid `oldProc`s.

Is there something else where the WinAPI can help fixing this problem?
Afaict using `SetWindowLongPtr` in that way does something like creating a child window(?) that way one could maybe query something?

Or is the bottom line just, that a WndProc cannot safely be unloaded anymore?

Comment: hooks in windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) were created in part so that you don't have to do things like this. when you talk about "hooks", are you referring to windows hooking or is this your own implementation?

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of the Hooking mechanism of Windows, so in the question, the term `hook` basically means intercepting WndProcs by overrriding it using `SetWindowLongPtr`.

Hooks look exactly like what I need then, a much cleaner approach! 
Do I need to find the `dwThreadId` of the original WndProc thread first, or is it the Thread that my hook will be executed in, so that Windows can cleanup on Thread Exit?

Comment: That's known as "sub-classing", and it's recommended to use `SetWindowSubclass` and `RemoveWindowSubclass` these days. That solves the add/remove order problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something else where the WinAPI can help fixing this problem?

Yes, actually. This is exactly the kind of situation that [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) was introduced to address. Let it handle the chaining and unchaining for you. Don't use `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)` at all anymore.

See [Safer subclassing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883) and [Subclassing Controls Using ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6) for more information.

That being said, depending on *why* you are subclassing, [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) may provide an alternative hook you can use for your intended purposes.

Comment: That's it and I've been figuring out which exact approach to take, as apparently SetWindowSubclass() does not work for messages sent between processes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) -> "Subclassing the window does not work for messages set between processes."

The downside of SetWindowsHookEx however is that the callback can't modify the messages, only intercept it completely (and thus probably re-send it).

I guess there is no ultimate solution to achieve both: hooking all messages as well as being able to modify them?

Comment: @MeFisto94 some hooks can modify data. It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve, which you have not explained yet

Comment: @MeFisto94: I am sure you are misunderstanding the documentation.  You cannot use window subclassing to call a `WndProc` in a different process than owns the window.  But in-process window subclassing will result in the subclass procedure receiving every windows message delivered to the window.  Now, messages from other processing may fail the integrity check and not be delivered anywhere, but that is an (intentional) limitation of the integrity check and not peculiar to subclassing, and definitely not a difference between `SetWindowSubclass()` and `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I confirmed it works with `SetWindowSubclass` even for out-of-process messages, I don't know how I initally assumed that sentence wrong.

Another hint for people trying to achieve the same: You actually need both, you need the WindowsHook to get a hold of the message thread in order to subclass the window. From there anything works as expected.

Thanks to all for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

> We effectively set the proc, that was in place when first hooking, as the topmost WndProc. This means, that all WndProcs, that have been added after myWndProc (e.g. all kinds of Overlays), suddenly won't be called anymore. Furthermore all hooks that are added afterwards point to invalid memory with their oldProc.

> This means, hooks done that way can't be properly unloaded without messing something up. While this would be fixable if all WndProcs belong to the same (our) codebase, this is not fixable with external code.

But you forget that `hwnd` is *your* window, created by your process, so it is under your control. It means you must design *your* module to properly restore the chain of window procs. There is no "external code" that can set *your* window proc to something else.

The emphasis is on "your window."

**EDIT**

Putting back the `WndProc` pointer will never affect the chain of window procedures. It is just that after putting it back, your procedure will not be called anymore, but the next one is called directly, which is exactly what you want.